# Writing a unit test to verify all ASP.NET MVC controllers inherit a base controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, inheritance, controller

Thanks for answering in advance. I have just started delving in unit-testing asp.net mvc web applications.

I have few controllers, all of which inherit from a BaseController (This BaseController is responsible for menus, tenant checking, etc). I wanted to know if there was a way that you can unit-test all controllers to ensure it is inheriting from the BaseController.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That almost sounds like it's more suited to static analysis, such as Visual Studio's Code Analysis feature (AKA "FxCop"). But I've written Code Analysis rules before, and I'm not sure I'd recommend it, unless you have a head full of hair, and wish to pull out all your hair!

So back to unit tests:

In your unit tests the strategy would be to locate all controller types in your controller assembly and ensure they have the right base class. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
Type[] allTypes = typeof(SomeTypeInTheAssembly).Assembly.GetExportedTypes();
Type[] allControllerTypes = allTypes.Where(
    t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t));
Type[] allControllerTypesExceptBaseClass = allControllerTypes.Except(
    t => t == typeof(BaseController);

// Assert that all controllers derive from BaseController
Assert.True(allControllerTypesExceptBaseClass.All(
    t => typeof(BaseController).IsAssignableFrom(t))
```

Comment: Thanks - this helped me get on the right track! (Plus - learned about Code Analysis - ur a champ!)